# How to use carriage return in a script template with a runtime mapping field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

Here is an example that illustrates the problem we are having with "mustache" and the carriage return.

In our script template, we need :

- a runtime mapping field : to compute a result (with a big script in our real case)
- conditional template : to build search criteria according to params existence (many criteria in our real case)

We use Elasticsearch 7.16 and kibana debug console to make our tests.

### We create this script template with this request :

```
POST _scripts/test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """{
      "runtime_mappings": {
        "result": {
          "type": "long",
          "script": {
            "source": "emit({{#foo}}{{foo}}{{/foo}}{{^foo}}0{{/foo}})"
          }
        }
      }
      {{#foo}}
        ,"fields": [
          "result"
        ]
      {{/foo}}
    }"""
  }
}
```

### Here are 2 examples of requests that show how this script works:

**Request 1 : Search request with param**

Return the computed field "result" with the "foo" parameter value (12345)

```
GET _search/template
{
  "id": "test",
  "params": {
    "foo": 12345
  }
}
```

**Request 2 : Search request without param**

Don't return computed field "result".

```
GET _search/template
{
  "id": "test"
}
```

Like i said before, in our real case we have a very big "painless" script in the computed field.
For more readability, we therefore wrote this script on several lines and that's when a problem appears.

### An error happened when we declare:

```
"source": "
  emit({{#foo}}{{foo}}{{/foo}}{{^foo}}0{{/foo}})
"
```

instead of:

```
"source": "emit({{#foo}}{{foo}}{{/foo}}{{^foo}}0{{/foo}})"
```

Due to the JSON specifications, we cannot use carriage returns otherwise we get the following error:
`Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value`

We also cannot use the notation with """ because it will conflict with the one used to declare the source of the script template.

Is there a trick to set the computed field script to multiple lines in Kibana debug console ?

Comment: [Here is the explanation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/72827) why  stored scripts are not supported for runtime mappings. Maybe, @javanna can chime in and explain how to deal with the above case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I knew I couldn't use stored scripts for runtime fields but I didn't know why. However, if the script of the computed field is defined directly inside the "runtime_mappings.source" field, it is possible to use both computed field and mustache templates. The only constraint is that the "runtime_mappings.source" field should not contain any carriage return. Maybe there is a trick to escape these carriage returns inside the script ?